# How to get new migrations to show up in the Migrate UI

Tags: migrations

My question is a general one: how do you get new migrations, which you've created via a custom module using Migrate, to show up in the Migrate UI at /admin/content/migrate ? What lines of code are necessary in your custom module for this?

Specifically, I'd like to know what's missing from a particular custom module (called ea_hub_migrations.module) that I've created. I created this by cutting down the migrate_example module, but after enabling ea_hub_migrations.module the migration group it defines isn't showing at /admin/content/migrate . By contrast, the migration I created with the module at https://drupal.org/node/1285276 does show up there. Here is the code for my custom module - I'd be very grateful if someone could take a look and tell me what's missing:

ea_hub_migrations.migrate.inc (included via ea_hub_migrations.info) - http://pastebin.com/KWMHd3gx

Comment: The code you linked to still has the hook "migrate_example_migrate_api". Is your module called "migrate_example" ?

Comment: @2pha, thanks I've fixed that, but still have the same issue after disabling and enabling the module and clearing my cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the function `*_migrate_api()` in `*.migrate.inc` should include the `$api` with the key `api` of 2, and the key `migrations` of the array for your migration.

If you have newly added your migration, drastically changing the code etc, you perhaps need to make Drupal recognise the hook you have just created in your migration module; a guaranteed way for that is to disable once and (re)enable your migration module.

Then you need register your migration.  If you use Drush,

```
drush migrate-register --group=YourMigrationGroupName
```

would do a job.  After Flusing all caches (`drush cc all` etc), you will see the migration in your migration UI (hopefully!).

I am not an expert, but the above is based on my recent experiences.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it (though I'm now getting "Processed 0 (0 created, 0 updated)", despite the fact that it imported many rows when I had it enabled earlier on my local site).

Comment: For me, `drush migrate-register` did the trick. Thanks